# Time interval based buckets in redis sorted set

Tags: redis

Is there any way to generate time interval based buckets using redis sorted set. I want to create different sorted sets in certain time interval (lets say 15 mins)

t1, t2 are scores

Key           SortedSet

bucket#V1     (t1,1),(t2,2).....  (commited bucket)

bucket#V1+15  (t3,1),(t4,2).....  (commited bucket)

bucket#V1+30  (t5,1),(t6,2).....  (current running bucket)

i.e. in 15 mins interval, it should automatically create new key and start ingesting data in new sorted set. V1+15 should start after 15 mins...

The second challenge is how to query commited buckets? (not running buckets where data still getting ingested).

The end goal is to query commited buckets first then query data in each bucket using time range queries (based on score i.e. ZRANGEBYSCORE)

Answer (score 0):

Your key is going to be something like DateTime.Now.SecondsSinceEpoch / TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15) Formatted as a fixed length string.  Here is a powershell script showing how to get the interval key value.  you can use a similar routine for storing data or requesting any past (or future) interval.  Here the interval is 3 seconds and the Epoch value is Jan 1, 1970 but can use anything you want.

```
1..7 | % { $interval = [int] (((get-date) - (epoch)).TotalSeconds / 3) ; $interval ; start-sleep -Seconds 1 }
514663592
514663593
514663593
514663593
514663594
514663594
514663594
```